# Remove duplicates algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, struct

I'm trying to write an algorithm to remove duplicates from a `vector<struct xxxx*>`.

```
struct xxxx{
    int value;     // This is just to make you understand
    xxxx* one; 
    xxxx* two;
}
```

As you see my struct it's like a tree but the pointers are not in order. The pointers can point to any(actually not any but most) of the others. And the vector doesn't contain the structs but pointers, so I couldn't use the std algorithms to help me neither.

I'm trying to delete duplicates with exactly same value and the same two pointers, but in the same time if I have two similar structs (Let's say `A` and `B`) and `C.one` or `C.two` points to `B`. Then I need to change it to `A` and viceversa.

In other words: if `A == B`  then remove `B` and change `C.one` to point `A`.

I think I can write the brute-force, so if there's no better algorithm I'll write it by myself.

Comment: Note that once you have done a replacement, you may introduce new duplicates.

Comment: 1) Did you mean `xxxx* one;` instead of `struct* one` ? 2) "the vector doesn't contain the structs but pointers, so I couldn't use the std algorithms" hmmm... why ?

Comment: !) Oh, yes. Didn't figured out. I'll change it now, 2) I wanted to use the std::unique() to remove duplicates and then try to fix the pointers. It was the fastest way I could think.

Comment: perhaps it's easier to try to fill your vector without any duplicates from the start?

Comment: _"And the vector doesn't contain the structs but pointers, so I couldn't use the std algorithms to help me neither."_ Eh? Why not?

Comment: IIUC, the complexity comes from the fact that when you remove a duplicate, you must change all the pointers to that duplicate and doing so may create more duplicates.  For that reason, removing duplicates is generally less efficient than incrementally building a helper container of non duplicates.  While I'm not experienced with std::unique() I can't believe it is flexible enough for that aspect of the problem.

Comment: @MadScientist I've already thought about it. But I need them before to remove.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because if i use std::unique it compares the pointers, as far as I know.

Comment: @JSF "and doing so may create more duplicates" Didn't think about that, the way the pointers are set it's really rare that this could happen but rare it's not impossible. TY.

Comment: @UmurilLyerood: It doesn't need to... tell it not to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I tried to explain the reasonable approach to a very similar problem to a coworker who had used an N squared solution to an N log N problem.

First create a helper struct, that is basically a wrapper around an xxxx* with a comparison operator checking the contents (not the pointer value) and probably with some other utility functions.  This wrapper struct isn't strictly needed vs. just using xxxx*, but from experience, I think it makes the task cleaner.

Create a std::set of those helper structs, into which you will only insert unique elements, and likely another set into which you will insert recursively unresolved elements.

Loop through the original vector and at each position recurse through its children.  If you hit a child already in the unique set, that is a final value for that child pointer.  If you hit a child that matches a unique element without being the one it matches, then fix the pointer that got you there.  If there is also the possibility of null pointers that should bottom the recursion, and if loops are possible you need to detect them (with that recursively unresolved set) and some decision about what to do with a loop.  At some point you hit resolved unique elements and add that to the unique set.

The performance and maybe even soundness of the idea depends on the depth and complexity of the loops and what you want to do with loops.  There are some messy cases where a loop would map onto another loop, but detecting that could be very tricky.  If your phase "like a tree" meant "no loops" then the recursion bottoms cleanly and efficiently without the extra complexity of explicitly managing the recursively unresolved elements.

Obviously I left out some of the grunt work detail around detecting unique / non-unique as you back out of the recursion and around detecting "already did it during an earlier recursion" as you hit an item in the main loop above the recursion.  But all those details should be pretty obvious as you write the relevant parts of the code.

Edit:  To understand how few node visits there are despite nesting a recursion inside a sequential loop, think from the point of view of the pointers.  We follow each pointer at most once (some duplicates are pre detected without following their pointers).  For N nodes, there are N top level pointers (if I understood your description correctly) and significantly less than 2N internal pointers (the more tree-like it is, the closer it will be to N-1 internal pointers, rather than 2N).  So each node is visited on average less than 3 times and a minority of those visits require both the pre lookup and the post recursion lookup, and each lookup is log U where U is the number of unique items found up to that point.  So we can trivially see a bound of `6 N log N`.

Comment: I like your idea. First of all, I have no loops and there could be null pointers. Value is a mask so I know where the null pointers will be, and I can handle it. Secondly, I was thinking about fix the set linear instead of the vector recursive, what do you think could it be better? so I don't fix the duplicates too, rigth? After all, I'll add sets and see if i can get this go to linear in some way. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't have loops, then the recursion lets you always resolve the children of an xxxx (either discover they are unique and add them to the set of unique, or discover their duplicate already in the set) BEFORE you need to decide whether the parent xxxx is unique.  So you can fix (if necessary) its pointers and then trivially check whether it is unique.

Comment: It may appear that nesting a recursion inside an outer sequential loop massively increases the number of visits, but it really is much more limited.  The key is to pre check "already visited" in some way before recursion at each level.  Assuming there is no convenient place to cram a true "visited" flag, you can use the unique set for that.  If before recursion it already matches something (maybe itself) already in the unique set, then there is no reason to recurse into it.  If it doesn't match before recursion, then you do the recursion and check again after recursion to see if it now matches